# How to configure log4j2.properties file for log4j2 to have a logger with 2 appenders with different levels?

Tags: java, log4j2

Can anyone help me, I have tryied so hard to make it work but I didn't succeed
here is my configuration file

```
name=PropertiesConfig
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=logs/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n


loggers=logfile
logger.logfile.name=com.mycompany.pack
logger.logfile.level = error

logger.logfile.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
logger.logfile.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
```

how can I set two different levels for appenders, for example, in console to display only from info and above and for file to display only from error and above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Threshold` property.

> Appender can have a threshold level associated with it independent of
>   the logger level. The Appender ignores any logging messages that have
>   a level lower than the threshold level.

For your case something like the following:

```
appender.console.Threshold = info
appender.file.Threshold = error
```

Comment: can you give me an example of how to use it, if I don't ask to much?

Comment: I've put those two lines and I get this error "ERROR File contains an invalid element or attribute "Threshold"" maybe I need some configuration for these thresholds properties?